# How to breakdown a method and process it

Tags: java, arrays

I am preparing for an exam next week, and I decided to look for some exam questions online for better preparation.
I came across this question and the answer is c. But I really want to know how or the step by step process to answer to answer a question like this. The part where I got stuck is trying to logically understand  how a `int m = mystery(n);` How can a number equal a method? Whenever I get to a question like this is their anything important I should breakdown first?

```
private int[] myStuff;
 /** Precondition : myStuff contains int values in no particular order.
 /*/ 
 public int mystery(int num)
 {
 for (int k = myStuff.length - 1; k >= 0; k--)
 {
 if (myStuff[k] < num)
 {
 return k;
 }
 }
 return -1;
 }

Which of the following best describes the contents of myStuff after the 
following statement has been executed?
 int m = mystery(n); 

(a) All values in positions 0 through m are less than n.
(b) All values in positions m+1 through myStuff.length-1 are 
less than n.
(c) All values in positions m+1 through myStuff.length-1 are 
greater than or equal to n.
(d) The smallest value is at position m. 
(e) The largest value that is smaller than n is at position m.
```

Comment: mystery() is a method returning an int value.  m is assigned the result of the function.  You have a lot of studying to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the sample code into a Java IDE such as Eclipse, Netbeans or IntelliJ and then step through the code in the debugger in one of those environments.

Given that you are starting out I will give you the remainder of the code that you need to make this compile and run

```
public class MysteriousAlright {
    private int[] myStuff;

    public int mystery(int num)
    {
        for (int k = myStuff.length - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
            if (myStuff[k] < num) {
                return k;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MysteriousAlright ma = new MysteriousAlright();

        ma.setMyStuff(new int[] {4,5,6,7});

        int m  = ma.mystery(5);
        System.out.println("I called ma.mystery(5) and now m is set to " + m);

        m  = ma.mystery(3);
        System.out.println("I called ma.mystery(3) and now m is set to " + m);

        m  = ma.mystery(12);
        System.out.println("I called ma.mystery(12) and now m is set to " + m);
    }

    public void setMyStuff(int[] myStuff) {
        this.myStuff = myStuff;
    }
}
```

You then need to learn how to use the debugger and/or write simple Unit Tests.

Stepping through the code a line at a time and watching the values of the variables change will help you in this learning context.

Here are two strategies that you can use to breakdown nonsense code like that which you have sadly encountered in this "educational" context.

**Black Box examination Strategy**
Temporarily ignore the logic in the mystery function, we treat the function as a black box that we cannot see into.

Look at what data gets passed in, what data is returned.

So for the member function called mystery we have

What goes in? : int num

What gets returned : an int, so a whole number.

There are two places where data is returned.

- Sometimes it returns k
- Sometimes it returns -1

Now we move on.

**White Box examination Strategy**

As the code is poorly written, a black box examination is insufficient to interpret its purpose.

A white box reading takes examines the member function's internal logic (In this case, pretty much the for loop)

The for loop visits every element in the array called `myStuff`, starting *at the end of the array*

k is the number that tracks the position of the visited element of the array. (Note we count down from the end of the array to 0)

If the number stored at the visited element *is less than* `num` (which is passed in) then return the *position of that element*..

If none of elements of the array are less than num then return -1

So mystery reports on the first position of the element in the array (starting from the end of the array) where num is bigger than that element.

Answer (score 2):

See this page to understand a method syntax
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_methods.htm

`int m = mystery(n);` means this method going to `return int value` and you are `assigning that value to a int variable m`. So your final result is `m`. the loop will run from the array's end position to 0. loop will break down when array's current position value is less than your parameter `n`. on that point it will return the loop's current position. s o now m=current loop position. If all the values of the loop is greater than n it will return -1 because if condition always fails.

Answer (score 1):

do you understand what a method is ?
this is pretty basic, the method `mystery` receives an int as a parameter and returns an int when you call it.
meaning, the variable `m` will be assigned the value that returns from the method `mystery` after you call it with `n` which is an int of some value.

Answer (score 1):

"The part where I got stuck is trying to logically understand how a int m = mystery(n); How can a number equal a method?"

A method may or may not return a value. One that doesn't return a value has a return type of void. A method can return a primitive value (like in your case int) or an object of any class. The name of the return type can be any of the eight primitive types defined in Java, the name of any class, or an interface.

If a method doesn't return a value, you can't assign the result of that method to a variable.

If a method returns a value, the calling method may or may not bother to store the returned value from a method in a variable.